# ElasticSearch phrase suggestor randomly returns 0 results

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm running ElasticSearch 2.3.5 on OS X, using the Node.JS client. Sometimes the `_suggest` endpoint returns 0 results -- this occurs at random, for example in a test suite where only four documents are indexed.

Is there any reason why the suggestor would return 0 results? This is causing my tests to fail about 50% the time.

The test suite goes through the following steps:

- Create a new, blank index

  - Supply a mapping for a document where `title: {type: 'string'}`
- Inject four documents with a `title` field using the `_bulk` API.

  - I am passing `refresh=true` to ensure the documents are indexed.
- A simple test queries the documents. They are all there.
- Request suggestions for an obvious misspelling. **50/50 chance of pass or fail**

I will create a self-contained example app to prove this if nobody can suggest anything obvious.

One observation: Lowercase misspellings (eg. `alhpa` for `alpha` have 100% success; the failures only occur when introducing creative misspellings like `viTOR` for `victor`. Quite possibly I could be imagining this behaviour, though, because the errors have been coming and going...)

---

Additional: Here's the wrapper function I've written for the ElasticSearch API:

```
didYouMean(input) {
  return this.conn.suggest({
    index: this.indexName,
    type: 'customdoc',
    body: {
      titles: {
        text: input,
        phrase: {
          field: 'title',
          direct_generator: [{
            // Only needs to be one character
            // long to suggest a correction
            field: 'title',
            suggest_mode: 'always',
            min_word_length: 1,
          }],
          highlight: {
            pre_tag: '<strong><em>',
            post_tag: '</em></strong>',
          },
        },
      },
    },
  });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suggestions are computed per shard. 
How many shards do you have in this index?
If more then 1, could you check if it happens on the index with one shard?

Comment: There are five shards in the cluster. I can't find away to adjust this using the Elasticsearch-js wrapper.

Comment: It can only be changed during index creation. You would need to create new index with settings shard number to 1 and reindex whole data to this new index. Here is documentation how to create such index: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-create-index.html

Comment: Marking as solved. This was tricky to achieve through the JS library but I found a way. Can confirm this produces consistent results -- the down-side is that some useful phrase suggestions are no longer forthcoming. They were probably produced due to random duplication of source documents across shards, increasing their word frequency.